# Reduce HTML collection to only elements meeting specific criteria

Tags: javascript

What would be the most elegant way to reduce the `labels` HTML collection to only those elements which `textContext` attribute value matches any string from the `text_criteria` array?

```
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name')
var textContent_criteria = ['Description', 'Category', 'Department', 'Justification']
```

I could do this with multiple for loops, but would prefer functional programming-inspired solution instead.

Comment: Elegance is definetly in the eye of the beholder.. I tend to think it's readability and performance, but most people nowadays think it's functional and one-liners. Or am I just getting old? Have you tried [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `.call` the `Array.prototoype.filter` function:

```js
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name');
var textContent_criteria = ['Description', 'Category', 'Department', 'Justification'];
var matchingLabels = Array.prototype.filter.call(
  labels,
  ({ textContent }) => textContent_criteria.includes(textContent)
);

console.log(matchingLabels);
```

```html
<div class="some-class-name">Description</div>
<div class="some-class-name">Bad Description</div>
<div class="some-class-name">Category</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of array methods `filter` and `some`:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name');
var textContent_criteria = ['Description', 'Category', 'Department', 'Justification'];
Array.from(labels).filter(label => textContent_criteria.some(criteria => label.textContent.includes(criteria)));
```

Comment: I think I cannot use filter on HTML collection, I need to convert it to array first as in CertainPerformance's answer (or `Array.from(labels)`)

Comment: @barciewicz I am sorry for the misleading information then, didn't know about that, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @barciewicz I have updated the answer, so that it won't confuse anyone further, thanks again.